# Ext2: Group Descriptors

Tags: java, filesystems, inode, ext2, superblock

I'm writing a Java program to go through and navigate into a ext2 filesystem image. I know my fs is revision 1 (or greater), so I know that there are copies of superblock in groups 0,1 and those that are powers of 3,5 and 7. My question is, what happens to the group descriptor when in a group without a superblock? is there any? if there is, does that mean that it's in the first block of the group? Where should I look for the inode table in my third group?

My fs has 3 groups (0,1,2), each 8192 blocks long with blocksize=1024.

Comment: Hey, hold on; do you know about loopback devices? Or do you run an OS which has no native ext2 support?

Comment: I'm working on windows7, so no native support

Comment: Well, you can always use a VM

Comment: The point isn't just to go through the fs, but to actually write the program to to do, as in a coursework assignment!

Comment: Uh, good luck then; I do hope you use `ByteBuffer` like crazy?

Comment: Yes I do, but I can't figure what to do in the third group...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out so I'll just leave the answer here for future references.

As it turns out, the Group Descriptor block contains group descriptors for each group, added one after another. Also a group descriptor has 32 bytes length (http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html#BLOCK-GROUP-DESCRIPTOR-TABLE). So if you want the gd of the n-th group, you should do n*32 inside the Group Descriptor Block.